# How to refresh AWS CloudWatch backward and forward token once expired?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

When you use AWS CLI and run the 'get-log-events' command, it returns all the events along with 'nextForwardToken' and 'nextBackwardToken'.

As the AWS documentation mentioned, the token expires after 24 hours.

My question is, how do you refresh the tokens after those are expired?

When I tried with an invalid token as the 'nextForwardToken', it returns the same token along with an empty event list.

Comment: Why do you want to store the output of a single command for so long? This isn't an authorization token.

Comment: We are storing token to get the events after the last request. @MunavirChavody

Comment: I don't think AWS will store the state of your command for so long. You might want to perform a new command.